# Status bar not sticking to top on Some iPads

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

We have an ionic1 and cordova hybrid app. On some iPads status bar dropping to a fixed position on screen. Same app works on iPhones and some iPads.

Some other details:

```
Project: Ionic1

Cordova Version: 8.1.2

"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
```

Preference set in config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

Code used in app.js

```
   if (window.StatusBar) {
         // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()){
            StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
            StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#C81B1B");  
        }else{
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, report it on the github repository https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/issues

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to set  `overlaysWebView` to `true` because you already create space for status bar.

```
 StatusBar.overlaysWebView(True);
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion, but this problems occurs only on few iPADs, our code is same for iPhone & iPADs.

Comment: Try first because this problem occur to me before